# NSIS Function with more than 1 parameters

Tags: nsis

Can a NSIS Function have more than one parameter?

Why wont this code compile? If I cant have more than 1 param for a function what are my other options(disregarding using a macro)?

Compile error:

> Function expects 1 parameters, got 4.  Usage: Function function_name

```
Outfile "test.exe"
Caption ""
Name ""

# Compile Error Here: "Function expects 1 parameters, got 4. Usage: Function function_name"
Function MyFunction p1 p2 p3
    DetailPrint "$p1, $p2, $p3"
FunctionEnd

Section
    DetailPrint "Hello World"
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to pass parameters in registers and/or on the [stack](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Pop,_Push,_Exch..._The_Stack):

```
Function onstack
pop $0
detailprint $0
FunctionEnd

Function reg0
detailprint $0
FunctionEnd

Section
push "Hello"
call onstack
strcpy $0 "World"
call reg0
SectionEnd
```

Comment: When you invoke a function you're allowed to pass it parameters inline. Does it use the stack or the registry for that?

Comment: @Ring No you cannot pass them inline. You can do it when using the dll::export plugin syntax but the compiler translates those into a push...

Comment: I was looking at the source of one of these functions: For most libraries they include a !macro definition that allows users to provide parameters inline. In the case of (explode http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Explode) the parameters are pushed and the return is popped.